# Exporting individual layers in Photoshop, keeping their sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, png, resolution

I‘m trying to export individual layers in Photoshop as PNGs, keeping their size. So if I have a layer that is 200×200 in a composition that is 1000×1000, I want to export just that layer as a PNG at 200×200. Is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure this question is on-topic, but it's the first question on the site, so here we go:

What you're looking for are layer based slices.

1. Select the layers you want to export, go to Layer > New Layer Based Slice(s)
2. Go to File > Save for Web & Devices...
3. When saving, choose "All User Slices"

If you have overlapping layers, which you will have more often than not, you might have to repeat the process a few times, hiding certain layers each time.

Answer (score 12):

File→Script→Export Layers to Files...

Make sure that *Trim Layers* is checked before exporting. This will save a 200×200 layer within a 1000×1000 composition as a 200×200 PNG file.

Comment: Hey, I have tried this, but I don't have the *scripts* option in *file.* I have Photoshop 6. How can I fix this?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I'd suggest you to consider checking out `File -> Export -> Layers to Files`.

Answer (score 9):

One thing you can do is:

1. Hide everything you don't want to see  (option click the "eye" icon of your chosen layer)
2. Select all
3. Copy merged
4. Create a new file (it'll automatically be the size of your clipboard, which should have resized to the size of actual pixels in your selection)
5. Paste and save as a PNG
6. Repeat!

There are scripts for this if you have an insane amount of layers, but an initial Google search didn't turn up a whole lot of these.

Answer (score 7):

**Solution number 1:**

Draw a Marquee selection around the element; 
choose Edit → Copy Merged
File → New; hit Return; 
“Paste.”

now you have your element ready to be saved in png format

**Solution number 2:**

right click on the layer (or group of layers) choose to duplicate the layer (or group) choose New as a destination

and you get a new document with your layer(s)

:)

Answer (score 2):

Select *Layer* and go to *Layer → Export As* in CS6.

Comment: This is now the most relevant answer (IMO). I'm currently running CC 2017 and this option is still there.