# Export layers to files sized according to content of layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, resize, photoshop-scripting

Sorry for the confusing title. What I did was scan 3-4 photos at a time and then crop those photos into new layers per scan and then I combined them all into one `.psd` file. So what I have now are several differently sized images on a larger canvas. This leaves extra white space when I run the `Layers -> Files script`. So now how can I resize all of the layers and save them as `.jpeg` files?

Comment: I actually just saw this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6918/export-layers-to-png-files-with-their-layer-sizes-with-photoshop?rq=1 - but would prefer jpegs if anyone knows a way.

Comment: Does the accepted answer to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1/exporting-individual-layers-in-photoshop-keeping-their-sizes) not work with JPGs?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried for a workaround using Photoshop Actions. Don't forget to keep the backup of your PSD.

Turn off all the layers and give your canvas a little bigger size before creating the action.
1 - Create an Action 
2 - Make visible one layer
3 - Trim the transparent pixels
5 - Save as Jpeg 
6 - Delete the layer
7 - Give the canvas size some bigger dimension.
8 - STOP

Comment: I use actions to do this sort of thing myself. Trim >>Transparent pixels is also my main thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is Slices. Although they're not intended exactly for this, they can do it.

Space out all your images, slice with the Slice tool accordingly, then Save For Web, pick a folder, and they'll all march right out as jpegs if you pick the right compression type.

The caveat is that your images will need to be spaced out. Any overlaps and the slicing won't work properly.

Comment: ... Providing that once the photos are spread out, the canvas size doesn't exceed what's accepted by the Save for Web function. From my reading of @jmalais question, there's many multiples of 4 photos in the PSD, meaning he could quite easy run afoul of this restriction.